# Accessing a third-party URL dragged onto my web page

Tags: javascript, browser, discord, drag-and-drop, static-files

I am developing a single-page web application. This web application consists of static files served by a web server at *example.org*. In particular, note that the web server at *example.org* cannot perform any tasks beyond serving these static files.

This web application contains a HTML `<input type="file">`. If the user selects an image or PDF file, the web application performs certain analysis operations on the file and provides the results.

Here, I am faced with an annoying UX limitation. My users frequently perform analysis on files received from third parties, typically via Discord. It has been requested that dragging a file attachment, or image, from a Discord message onto the web application should perform analysis.

Adding a simple `drop` handler to the application will only receive a URL to the Discord attachment, of the form `https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/identifier>/<filename>`. As this is a third-party resource, I am not able to programmatically retrieve and inspect data from it. *(The Discord CDN does not set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.)*

---

All operations must be performed in client-side JavaScript. It is impossible to, say, have the *example.org* web server request the URL for me. Do I have any way to analyze the contents of this user-dropped file (URL)?

Comment: doubt you can do anything